# Retrieve sitemap from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to retrieve sitemap from databse in asp.net? Can somebody provide any link which explain the process?

Comment: How is your website structure stored in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create your own SiteMapProvider. Here are few articles for achieving that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/05/06/WickedCode/

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130070308/http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/articles/52749.aspx)